How not to return empty cell with ArrayFormula and condition to ignore
I have a sheet with a pivot table. I want to return it by line to import it elsewhere. I created an array formula for this.
Here is my formula :
=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(flatten(PROPER('Doc'!A1)&""&'Doc'!G19:G29&""&'Doc'!E19:E29&""&'Doc'!F19:F29&""&'Doc'!J18:O18&""&'Doc'!J19:O29);""))

I don't want to return a line if a cell within 'Doc'!J19:O29 is empty to avoid having to much line in the generated doc.
Also I would like to ignore some line from 'Doc'!G19:G29 when there is the word "avoid". I could not find a way to do it.
I tried adding a IF condition but did not work.
=ArrayFormula(if('Doc'!G19:G29="Avoid";;SPLIT(flatten(PROPER('Doc'!A1)&""&'Doc'!G19:G29&""&'Doc'!E19:E29&""&'Doc'!F19:F29&""&'Doc'!J18:O18&""&'Doc'!J19:O29);"")))

Here is the exemple :

Thank you

Try:
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(BYROW(SPLIT(flatten(PROPER('Doc'!A1)&""&'Doc'!G19:G29&""&'Doc'!E19:E29&""&'Doc'!F19:F29&""&'Doc'!J18:O18&""&'Doc'!J19:O29);""),LAMBDA(r;IF(OR(COUNTBLANK(r);COUNTIF("Avoid";r));;r))),"where Col1 is not null"))


Thank you. Its already nicer but there is now empty line in the result. Is there a way to avoid returning them, or it's only by filtering them?

Working like a sharm! Thank you. I guess about my second question, i can add it to the query also? How can I add "and Col2 is like Avoid" ?

try the updated formula.

IS there a way to return empty column when value are not available to get consistant table ?
